# How to know if my non-ViewController class has loaded (like viewDidLoad)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am sure this is an amateur question, but I am starting to develop in osx, and I created an NSTableView that consists of two classes. One is the VC where it lives, and the other one is a 'TableHelper' class that sets it up.

Since the TableHelper class is the delegate and dataSource of my table, I want to be able to set some things up before it loads (like a viewDidLoad method) is there an equivalent for this NSObject, NSTableViewDelegate/DataSource class?

Comment: What do you mean "before it loads"? Before you create an instance of the class, or before the controller that it's the source for loads its view?

Comment: Before the view controller loads its view.. (which is creating an instance of the class, I'm guessing)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether your table helper is created in code or in a storyboard/xib.

If code, then there's no delayed loading; it exists when you create it.  If storyboard/xib, then you're looking for the `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: I want to do some set up when I create it, is there a method being called when an instance of a NSTableView (delegate and DataSource) class is created? (TableHelper is a class in code)

Comment: It's still not clear exactly what your situation is.  Can you post the code and location where you **create** a `TableHelper` instance?

Comment: Phillip, thanks, I solved my problem by making the ViewController the delegate of the TableView. Problem was that the class that I defined as a delegate was an NSObject..!

Comment: Glad you can move on...however, having a delegate that's a NSObject subclass is valid if you really want to do it.  Using the view controller is more convenient for making UI changes when the user interacts with the table but it's not a requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway!